# How to check the submitted date is not before the today's date in laravel 5 request class?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Here is my code in request class.

```
public function rules()
{


    return [
        'title' => 'required',
        'eventDate' => 'required|date|before:today',


    ];
}

public function messages(){
    return [
        'title.required' => 'Title is required.',
        'eventDate.before' => 'Event Date is already passed',
        'eventDate.required' => 'Event Date is required.',

    ];
}`
```

This is the view class code

```
@if($errors->has('eventDate.required'))
    <p style="color: red">{{$errors->first('eventDate.required')}}</p>
@endif
@if($errors->has('eventDate.before'))
    <p style="color: red">{{$errors->first('eventDate.before')}}</p>
@endif
```

I want to compare the submitted date with today's date. If submitted date is earlier date than today's date, an error message should be displayed.But there should be  mistakes in code.

[image]

Comment: its mean there is some error in your routes. can you update your routes in your question section

Comment: Actually route error comes after I added this  'eventDate' => 'required|date|before:today',

Comment: can you share your error message ? and share your code sample, so we can guide you properly

Comment: error message is updated again. Actually I'm not sure about the view class code where I tried to get from request class. Please can you help on that.

Comment: Check your route. Looks like you have defined the route with wrong verb (GET, POST).

Comment: Apart from route, are there any errors in above code? Because after I removed the |date|before:today' from  'eventDate'=> 'required|date|before:today' it will work correctly

Comment: Post the complete code for the validation so we can take a look at potential errors.